# JsonPath Jayway Java implementation cannot read values

Tags: java, jsonpath, jayway

I want to read objects from the main array filtering by refPath using JsonPath Jayway Java implementation.

My input looks like this:

```
[
   {
      "2be3d660-cab0-4db8-83b9-1baf212270c5" : {
         "refPath" : [
            "e0586818-ba2c-4b65-afec-3c48d817b584",
            "06c089a6-4de0-43d3-8dc7-181addf4c933",
            "d5413a18-ac33-426c-982d-bb25ce4e4bf6"
         ],
         "elementId" : "12c5750e-9753-43f1-8987-9dfc3a830bbe",
         "modified" : false
      },
      "191b1bab-c269-495f-ac4f-8b4d30df95a1" : {
         "refPath" : [
            "e0586818-ba2c-4b65-afec-3c48d817b584",
            "f7df7cff-bf6d-49da-bc44-90d61f233d3b"
         ],
         "elementId" : "04691514-566b-47ef-8f69-e31884bde7b2",
         "modified" : false
      },
      "6a2acd79-135f-4688-9219-158f91d9c6cf" : {
         "refPath" : [
            "e0586818-ba2c-4b65-afec-3c48d817b584",
            "f5177f79-e2f1-4419-b46a-7d4cc1c4fae5"
         ],
         "elementId" : "04691514-566b-47ef-8f69-e31884bde7b2",
         "modified" : false
      }
   }
]
```

and I want to find all objects containing these two refPath values: `"e0586818-ba2c-4b65-afec-3c48d817b584"` and `"06c089a6-4de0-43d3-8dc7-181addf4c933"`

So my expected result from JsonPath looks like:

```
[
       {
          "2be3d660-cab0-4db8-83b9-1baf212270c5" : {
             "refPath" : [
                "e0586818-ba2c-4b65-afec-3c48d817b584",
                "06c089a6-4de0-43d3-8dc7-181addf4c933",
                "d5413a18-ac33-426c-982d-bb25ce4e4bf6"
             ],
             "elementId" : "12c5750e-9753-43f1-8987-9dfc3a830bbe",
             "modified" : false
          }
       }
]
```

[image]

Even with if I only try to find `"e0586818-ba2c-4b65-afec-3c48d817b584"`, I get an error message "Could not determine value type".

Does anybody have an idea how the JsonPath expression must look like for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `subsetof` [filter operator](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#filter-operators).

```
$[*][*][?(['e0586818-ba2c-4b65-afec-3c48d817b584','06c089a6-4de0-43d3-8dc7-181addf4c933'] subsetof @.refPath)]
```

Output will not include the key `2be3d660-cab0-4db8-83b9-1baf212270c5`

```
[
   {
      "refPath" : [
         "e0586818-ba2c-4b65-afec-3c48d817b584",
         "06c089a6-4de0-43d3-8dc7-181addf4c933",
         "d5413a18-ac33-426c-982d-bb25ce4e4bf6"
      ],
      "elementId" : "12c5750e-9753-43f1-8987-9dfc3a830bbe",
      "modified" : false
   }
]
```